# Hibernate query with embedded Id

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, left-join

In my application I have three classes linked each other with an embedded class.

The Ordine class with id Id

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ordine")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Ordine implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "ordine_id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "company_id")
private Long companyId;
....
```

The OrdineUtente class with id that is an embedded id

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ordini_vettori")
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "id.ordine", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ordine_id")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "id.utente", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "utente_id")) })
public class OrdineUtente implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private OrdineUtenteId id;

    @Column(name = "sort_order")
    private Integer sortOrder;
    ....
}
```

and the embeddable class OrdineUtenteId

```
@Embeddable
public class OrdineUtenteId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToOne
    private Ordine ordine;

    @ManyToOne
    private UserApp utente;
    ....
}
```

How I can make a query with join in Hibernate to find all User associated with our order?

I tried to write this query:

```
SELECT ordine FROM Ordine ordine 
LEFT JOIN OrdineUtente ordineUtente 
WHERE ordine.id = ordineUtente.id.ordine.id 
AND ordineUtente.id.utente.userId = :userId
```

But it isn't correct because the join value is missing. The `:userId` parameter is passed from external.

Comment: What's the complete error?